# Find all the five digit primes with this property

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all the five digit prime numbers such that the product of their digits equals
some number squared multiplied by another number such  as  7^2  * 5   for example.

Comment: HAve you tried anything?

Comment: *Any* number equals the product of a square and some number

Comment: oops, sorry I misread sum instead of product, the list contains $6021$ primes. How many do you have?

Comment: That's very true. At the very least, you can write something as a product of a number and one squared.

Comment: No  that's not true

Comment: Send the list Draks

Comment: @draks: You interpreted it as product of the digits is neither zero nor squarefree...? I also got 6021.

Comment: @daniel yes, sorry for the delay and thanks for confirmation. _at_Kelly, "please" would have been nice, but here you go...

Answer (score 3):

$11119,11149,11159,11177,11197,11239,11243,11261,11279,11287,11299,11329,11353,11369,11383,11393,11399,11411,11423,11437,11443,11447,11467,11471,11483,11489,11491,11497,11519,11549,11551,11579,11587,11593,11597,11621,11633,11677,11681,11689,11699,11717,11719,11743,11777,11779,11783,11789,11813,11821,11827,11831,11833,11839,11863,11867,11887,11897,11923,11927,11933,11939,11941,11953,11959,11969,11971,11981,11987,12119,12143,12149,12161,12163,12197,12211,12227,12239,12241,12251,12253,12263,12269,12277,12281,12289,12323,12329,12343,12347,12373,12377,12379,12391,12413,12421,12433,12437,12451,12457,12473,12479,12487,12491,12497,12527,12539,12541,12547,12553,12569,12577,12583,12589,12611,12613,12619,12637,12641,12647,12653,12659,12671,12689,12697,12721,12739,12743,12757,12763,12781,12791,12799,12821,12823,12829,12841,12853,12889,12893,12899,12911,12917,12919,12923,12941,12953,12959,12967,12973,12979,12983,13147,13159,13163,13177,13183,13187,13219,13229,13241,13249,13259,13267,13291,13297,13313,13327,13331,13337,13339,13367,13381,13397,13399,13411,13417,13421,13441,13451,13457,13463,13469,13477,13487,13499,13513,13523,13537,13553,13567,13577,13591,13597,13613,13619,13627,13633,13649,13669,13679,13681,13687,13691,13693,13697,13723,13729,13757,13759,13763,13781,13789,13799,13829,13831,13841,13859,13873,13877,13879,13883,13913,13921,13931,13933,13963,13967,13997,13999,14143,14149,14153,14159,14173,14177,14197,14221,14243,14249,14251,14281,14293,14321,14323,14327,14341,14347,14369,14387,14389,14411,14419,14423,14431,14437,14447,14449,14461,14479,14489,14519,14533,14537,14543,14549,14551,14557,14561,14563,14591,14593,14621,14627,14629,14633,14639,14653,14657,14669,14683,14699,14713,14717,14723,14731,14737,14741,14747,14753,14759,14767,14771,14779,14783,14797,14813,14821,14827,14831,14843,14851,14867,14869,14879,14887,14891,14897,14923,14929,14939,14947,14951,14957,14969,14983,15139,15149,15187,15193,15199,15227,15233,15241,15259,15263,15269,15277,15287,15289,15299,15313,15319,15329,15331,15349,15359,15361,15373,15377,15383,15391,15413,15427,15439,15443,15451,15461,15467,15473,15493,15497,15511,15527,15541,15551,15559,15569,15581,15583,15619,15629,15641,15643,15647,15649,15661,15667,15679,15683,15727,15733,15737,15739,15749,15767,15773,15787,15791,15797,15817,15823,15859,15877,15881,15887,15889,15913,15919,15923,15937,15959,15971,15973,15991,16127,16139,16141,16183,16187,16189,16193,16217,16223,16229,16231,16249,16253,16267,16273,16319,16333,16339,16349,16361,16363,16369,16381,16411,16417,16421,16427,16433,16447,16451,16453,16477,16481,16487,16493,16519,16529,16547,16553,16561,16567,16573,16619,16631,16633,16649,16651,16657,16661,16673,16691,16693,16699,16729,16741,16747,16759,16763,16787,16811,16823,16829,16831,16843,16871,16879,16883,16889,16921,16927,16931,16937,16943,16963,16979,16981,16987,16993,17117,17137,17159,17167,17183,17189,17191,17239,17257,17291,17293,17299,17317,17327,17333,17341,17359,17377,17383,17387,17389,17393,17417,17419,17431,17443,17449,17467,17471,17477,17483,17489,17491,17497,17519,17539,17551,17569,17573,17579,17581,17597,17599,17623,17627,17657,17659,17669,17681,17683,17713,17729,17737,17747,17749,17761,17783,17789,17791,17827,17837,17839,17851,17863,17881,17891,17911,17921,17923,17929,17939,17957,17959,17971,17977,17981,17987,17989,18119,18121,18127,18131,18133,18143,18149,18169,18181,18191,18199,18211,18217,18223,18229,18233,18251,18253,18257,18269,18287,18289,18311,18313,18329,18341,18353,18367,18371,18379,18397,18413,18427,18433,18439,18443,18451,18457,18461,18481,18493,18517,18521,18523,18539,18541,18553,18583,18587,18593,18617,18637,18661,18671,18679,18691,18713,18719,18731,18743,18749,18757,18773,18787,18793,18797,18839,18859,18869,18899,18911,18913,18917,18919,18947,18959,18973,18979,19121,19139,19141,19157,19163,19181,19183,19211,19213,19219,19231,19237,19249,19259,19267,19273,19289,19319,19333,19373,19379,19381,19387,19391,19417,19421,19423,19427,19429,19433,19441,19447,19457,19463,19469,19471,19477,19483,19489,19531,19541,19543,19553,19559,19571,19577,19583,19597,19661,19681,19687,19697,19699,19717,19727,19739,19751,19753,19759,19763,19777,19793,19813,19819,19841,19843,19853,19861,19867,19889,19891,19913,19919,19927,19937,19949,19961,19963,19973,19979,19991,19993,19997,21121,21139,21143,21149,21163,21169,21179,21187,21191,21193,21211,21221,21227,21247,21269,21277,21283,21313,21319,21323,21341,21347,21377,21379,21383,21391,21397,21419,21433,21467,21481,21487,21491,21493,21499,21521,21523,21529,21557,21559,21563,21569,21577,21587,21589,21599,21611,21613,21617,21647,21649,21661,21673,21683,21727,21737,21739,21757,21767,21773,21787,21799,21817,21821,21839,21841,21851,21859,21863,21871,21881,21893,21911,21929,21937,21943,21961,21977,21991,21997,22111,22123,22129,22133,22147,22153,22157,22159,22171,22189,22193,22229,22247,22259,22271,22273,22277,22279,22283,22291,22343,22349,22367,22369,22381,22391,22397,22433,22441,22447,22453,22469,22481,22483,22511,22531,22541,22543,22549,22567,22571,22573,22613,22619,22621,22637,22639,22643,22651,22669,22679,22691,22697,22699,22717,22721,22727,22739,22741,22751,22769,22777,22783,22787,22811,22817,22853,22859,22861,22871,22877,22921,22937,22943,22961,22963,22973,22993,23131,23143,23159,23167,23173,23189,23197,23227,23251,23269,23279,23291,23293,23297,23311,23321,23327,23333,23339,23357,23369,23371,23399,23417,23431,23447,23459,23473,23497,23531,23537,23539,23549,23557,23561,23563,23567,23581,23593,23599,23623,23627,23629,23633,23663,23669,23671,23677,23687,23689,23719,23741,23743,23747,23753,23761,23767,23773,23789,23813,23819,23827,23831,23833,23857,23869,23873,23879,23887,23893,23899,23911,23917,23929,23957,23971,23977,23981,23993,24113,24121,24133,24137,24151,24169,24179,24181,24197,24223,24229,24239,24247,24251,24281,24317,24329,24337,24359,24371,24373,24379,24391,24413,24419,24421,24439,24443,24469,24473,24481,24499,24517,24527,24533,24547,24551,24571,24593,24611,24623,24631,24659,24671,24677,24683,24691,24697,24733,24749,24763,24767,24781,24793,24799,24821,24841,24847,24851,24859,24877,24889,24917,24919,24923,24943,24953,24967,24971,24977,24979,24989,25121,25127,25147,25153,25163,25169,25183,25189,25219,25229,25237,25243,25247,25253,25261,25321,25339,25343,25349,25357,25367,25373,25391,25411,25423,25439,25447,25453,25457,25463,25469,25471,25523,25537,25541,25561,25577,25579,25583,25589,25621,25633,25639,25643,25657,25667,25673,25679,25693,25717,25733,25741,25747,25759,25763,25771,25793,25799,25819,25841,25847,25849,25867,25873,25889,25913,25919,25931,25933,25939,25943,25951,25969,25981,25997,25999,26111,26113,26119,26141,26153,26161,26171,26177,26183,26189,26227,26237,26249,26251,26261,26263,26267,26293,26297,26317,26321,26339,26347,26357,26371,26387,26393,26399,26417,26423,26431,26437,26449,26459,26479,26489,26497,26513,26539,26557,26561,26573,26591,26597,26627,26633,26641,26647,26669,26681,26683,26687,26693,26699,26711,26713,26717,26723,26729,26731,26737,26759,26777,26783,26813,26821,26833,26839,26849,26861,26863,26879,26881,26891,26893,26921,26927,26947,26951,26953,26959,26981,26987,26993,27127,27143,27179,27191,27197,27211,27239,27241,27253,27259,27271,27277,27281,27283,27299,27329,27337,27361,27367,27397,27427,27431,27437,27449,27457,27479,27481,27487,27527,27529,27539,27541,27551,27581,27583,27611,27617,27631,27647,27653,27673,27689,27691,27697,27733,27737,27739,27743,27749,27751,27763,27767,27773,27779,27791,27793,27799,27817,27823,27827,27847,27851,27883,27893,27917,27919,27941,27943,27947,27953,27961,27967,27983,27997,28111,28123,28151,28163,28181,28183,28211,28219,28229,28277,28279,28283,28289,28297,28319,28349,28351,28387,28393,28411,28429,28433,28439,28447,28463,28477,28493,28499,28513,28517,28537,28541,28547,28549,28559,28571,28573,28579,28591,28597,28619,28621,28627,28631,28643,28649,28657,28661,28663,28669,28687,28697,28711,28723,28729,28751,28753,28759,28771,28789,28793,28813,28817,28837,28843,28859,28867,28871,28879,28921,28927,28933,28949,28961,28979,29123,29129,29131,29137,29147,29153,29167,29173,29179,29191,29221,29231,29243,29251,29269,29287,29297,29311,29327,29333,29339,29347,29363,29383,29387,29389,29399,29411,29423,29429,29437,29443,29453,29473,29483,29527,29531,29537,29567,29569,29573,29581,29587,29599,29611,29629,29633,29641,29663,29669,29671,29683,29717,29723,29741,29753,29759,29761,29789,29819,29833,29837,29851,29863,29867,29873,29879,29881,29917,29921,29927,29947,29959,29983,29989,31123,31139,31147,31153,31159,31177,31181,31183,31189,31193,31219,31223,31231,31237,31247,31249,31253,31259,31267,31277,31319,31321,31327,31333,31337,31357,31379,31387,31391,31393,31397,31469,31477,31481,31489,31513,31531,31541,31543,31547,31567,31573,31583,31627,31643,31649,31657,31663,31667,31687,31699,31723,31727,31729,31741,31769,31771,31793,31799,31817,31847,31849,31859,31873,31883,31891,31957,31963,31973,31981,31991,32119,32141,32143,32159,32173,32183,32189,32191,32213,32233,32237,32251,32257,32261,32297,32299,32321,32323,32327,32341,32353,32359,32363,32369,32371,32377,32381,32411,32413,32423,32429,32441,32443,32467,32479,32491,32497,32531,32533,32537,32561,32563,32569,32573,32579,32587,32611,32621,32633,32647,32653,32687,32693,32713,32717,32719,32749,32771,32779,32783,32789,32797,32831,32833,32839,32843,32869,32887,32911,32917,32933,32939,32941,32957,32969,32971,32983,32987,32993,32999,33113,33119,33149,33151,33161,33179,33181,33191,33199,33211,33223,33247,33287,33289,33311,33317,33329,33331,33343,33347,33349,33353,33359,33377,33391,33413,33427,33457,33461,33469,33479,33487,33493,33521,33529,33533,33547,33563,33569,33577,33581,33587,33589,33599,33613,33617,33619,33623,33629,33637,33641,33647,33679,33713,33721,33739,33749,33751,33757,33767,33769,33773,33791,33797,33811,33827,33829,33851,33857,33863,33871,33889,33893,33911,33923,33931,33937,33941,33961,33967,33997,34123,34127,34129,34141,34147,34157,34159,34171,34183,34211,34213,34217,34231,34253,34259,34261,34267,34273,34283,34297,34313,34319,34327,34337,34351,34361,34367,34369,34381,34421,34429,34439,34457,34469,34471,34483,34487,34499,34511,34513,34519,34537,34543,34549,34583,34589,34591,34613,34631,34649,34651,34667,34673,34679,34687,34693,34721,34729,34739,34747,34757,34759,34763,34781,34819,34841,34843,34847,34849,34871,34877,34883,34897,34913,34919,34939,34949,34961,34963,34981,35129,35141,35149,35153,35159,35221,35227,35251,35257,35267,35279,35281,35291,35311,35317,35323,35327,35339,35353,35363,35381,35393,35419,35423,35437,35447,35449,35461,35491,35521,35527,35531,35533,35537,35543,35569,35573,35591,35593,35597,35617,35671,35677,35729,35731,35747,35753,35759,35771,35797,35831,35837,35839,35851,35863,35869,35879,35897,35899,35911,35923,35933,35951,35963,35969,35977,35983,35993,35999,36131,36137,36151,36161,36187,36191,36217,36229,36241,36251,36263,36269,36277,36293,36299,36313,36319,36341,36343,36353,36373,36383,36389,36433,36451,36457,36467,36469,36473,36479,36493,36497,36523,36527,36529,36541,36551,36559,36563,36571,36583,36587,36599,36629,36637,36643,36653,36671,36677,36683,36691,36697,36713,36721,36739,36749,36761,36767,36779,36781,36787,36791,36793,36821,36833,36847,36857,36871,36877,36887,36899,36913,36919,36923,36929,36931,36943,36947,36973,36979,36997,37117,37123,37139,37159,37171,37181,37189,37199,37217,37223,37243,37253,37273,37277,37313,37321,37337,37339,37357,37361,37363,37369,37379,37397,37423,37441,37447,37463,37483,37489,37493,37517,37529,37537,37547,37549,37561,37567,37571,37573,37579,37589,37591,37619,37633,37643,37649,37657,37663,37691,37693,37699,37717,37747,37781,37783,37799,37811,37813,37831,37847,37853,37861,37871,37879,37889,37897,37951,37957,37963,37967,37987,37991,37993,37997,38113,38119,38149,38153,38167,38177,38183,38189,38197,38219,38231,38237,38239,38261,38273,38281,38287,38299,38317,38321,38327,38329,38333,38351,38371,38377,38393,38431,38447,38449,38453,38459,38461,38543,38557,38561,38567,38569,38593,38611,38629,38639,38651,38653,38669,38671,38677,38693,38699,38711,38713,38723,38729,38737,38747,38749,38767,38783,38791,38821,38833,38839,38851,38861,38867,38873,38891,38917,38921,38923,38933,38953,38959,38971,38977,38993,39113,39119,39133,39139,39157,39161,39163,39181,39191,39199,39217,39227,39229,39233,39239,39241,39251,39293,39313,39317,39323,39341,39343,39359,39367,39371,39373,39383,39397,39419,39439,39443,39451,39461,39499,39511,39521,39541,39551,39563,39569,39581,39619,39623,39631,39659,39667,39671,39679,39719,39727,39733,39749,39761,39769,39779,39791,39799,39821,39827,39829,39839,39841,39847,39857,39863,39869,39877,39883,39887,39929,39937,39953,39971,39979,39983,39989,41113,41117,41131,41141,41143,41149,41161,41177,41179,41183,41189,41213,41221,41227,41231,41233,41243,41257,41263,41269,41281,41299,41333,41341,41351,41357,41381,41387,41389,41399,41411,41413,41443,41453,41467,41479,41491,41513,41519,41521,41539,41543,41549,41579,41593,41597,41611,41617,41621,41627,41641,41647,41651,41659,41669,41681,41687,41719,41729,41737,41759,41761,41771,41777,41813,41843,41849,41851,41863,41879,41887,41893,41897,41911,41927,41941,41947,41953,41957,41959,41969,41981,41983,41999,42131,42139,42157,42169,42179,42181,42187,42193,42197,42221,42223,42227,42239,42257,42281,42283,42293,42299,42323,42331,42337,42349,42359,42373,42379,42391,42397,42433,42437,42443,42451,42457,42461,42463,42467,42473,42487,42491,42499,42533,42557,42569,42571,42577,42589,42611,42641,42643,42649,42667,42677,42683,42689,42697,42719,42727,42737,42743,42751,42767,42773,42787,42793,42797,42821,42829,42839,42841,42853,42859,42863,42899,42923,42929,42937,42943,42953,42961,42967,42979,42989,43117,43133,43151,43159,43177,43189,43223,43237,43261,43271,43283,43291,43313,43319,43321,43331,43391,43397,43399,43411,43427,43441,43451,43457,43481,43487,43499,43517,43541,43543,43573,43577,43579,43591,43597,43613,43627,43633,43649,43651,43661,43669,43691,43711,43717,43721,43753,43759,43777,43781,43783,43787,43789,43793,43853,43867,43889,43891,43913,43933,43943,43951,43961,43963,43969,43973,43987,43991,43997,44111,44119,44123,44129,44131,44159,44171,44179,44189,44221,44249,44257,44263,44267,44269,44273,44279,44281,44293,44351,44357,44371,44381,44383,44389,44417,44449,44453,44483,44491,44497,44519,44531,44533,44537,44543,44549,44563,44579,44587,44617,44621,44623,44633,44641,44647,44651,44657,44683,44687,44699,44711,44729,44741,44753,44771,44773,44777,44789,44797,44819,44839,44843,44851,44867,44879,44887,44893,44917,44927,44939,44953,44959,44963,44971,44983,44987,45119,45121,45127,45131,45137,45139,45161,45179,45181,45191,45197,45233,45247,45259,45263,45281,45289,45293,45317,45319,45329,45337,45341,45343,45361,45377,45389,45413,45427,45433,45439,45481,45491,45497,45523,45533,45541,45553,45557,45569,45587,45589,45599,45613,45631,45641,45659,45667,45673,45677,45691,45697,45737,45751,45757,45763,45767,45779,45817,45821,45823,45827,45833,45841,45853,45863,45869,45887,45893,45943,45949,45953,45959,45971,45979,45989,46133,46141,46147,46153,46171,46181,46183,46187,46199,46219,46229,46237,46261,46271,46273,46279,46327,46337,46349,46351,46381,46399,46411,46439,46441,46447,46451,46457,46471,46477,46489,46499,46511,46523,46549,46559,46567,46573,46589,46591,46619,46633,46639,46643,46649,46663,46679,46681,46687,46691,46723,46727,46747,46751,46757,46769,46771,46811,46817,46819,46829,46831,46853,46861,46867,46877,46889,46919,46933,46957,46993,46997,47111,47119,47123,47129,47137,47143,47147,47149,47161,47189,47221,47237,47251,47269,47279,47287,47293,47297,47317,47339,47351,47353,47363,47381,47387,47389,47417,47419,47431,47441,47459,47491,47497,47513,47521,47527,47533,47543,47563,47569,47581,47591,47599,47623,47629,47639,47653,47657,47659,47681,47699,47711,47713,47717,47737,47741,47743,47777,47779,47791,47797,47819,47837,47843,47857,47869,47881,47911,47917,47933,47939,47947,47951,47963,47969,47977,47981,48119,48121,48131,48157,48163,48179,48187,48193,48197,48221,48239,48247,48259,48271,48281,48299,48311,48313,48337,48341,48353,48371,48383,48397,48413,48437,48449,48463,48473,48479,48481,48487,48491,48497,48523,48527,48533,48539,48541,48563,48571,48589,48593,48611,48619,48623,48647,48649,48661,48673,48677,48679,48731,48733,48751,48757,48761,48767,48779,48781,48787,48799,48817,48821,48823,48847,48857,48859,48869,48871,48883,48889,48947,48953,48973,48989,48991,49117,49121,49123,49139,49157,49169,49171,49177,49193,49199,49211,49223,49253,49261,49277,49279,49297,49331,49333,49339,49363,49367,49369,49391,49393,49411,49417,49429,49433,49451,49459,49463,49477,49481,49499,49523,49529,49531,49537,49547,49549,49559,49597,49613,49627,49633,49639,49663,49667,49669,49681,49697,49711,49727,49739,49741,49747,49757,49783,49787,49789,49811,49823,49831,49843,49853,49871,49877,49891,49919,49921,49927,49937,49939,49943,49957,49991,49993,49999,...
$

Answer (score 2):

$...,51133,51151,51157,51169,51193,51197,51199,51229,51239,51241,51257,51263,51283,51287,51329,51341,51343,51347,51349,51361,51383,51413,51419,51421,51427,51431,51437,51439,51449,51461,51473,51479,51481,51487,51511,51517,51521,51539,51551,51563,51577,51581,51593,51599,51613,51631,51637,51647,51659,51673,51679,51683,51691,51719,51749,51767,51769,51787,51797,51817,51827,51829,51839,51853,51859,51869,51871,51893,51899,51913,51929,51941,51949,51971,51973,51977,51991,52121,52127,52147,52153,52163,52177,52181,52183,52189,52223,52237,52249,52253,52259,52267,52289,52291,52313,52321,52361,52363,52369,52379,52387,52391,52433,52453,52457,52489,52511,52517,52529,52541,52543,52553,52561,52567,52571,52579,52583,52627,52631,52639,52667,52673,52691,52697,52721,52727,52733,52747,52757,52769,52783,52813,52817,52837,52859,52861,52879,52883,52889,52919,52937,52951,52957,52963,52967,52973,52981,52999,53113,53129,53147,53149,53161,53173,53189,53197,53231,53233,53239,53267,53269,53279,53281,53299,53323,53327,53353,53359,53377,53381,53411,53419,53437,53441,53453,53479,53527,53549,53551,53569,53591,53593,53597,53611,53617,53623,53629,53633,53639,53653,53657,53681,53693,53699,53717,53719,53731,53759,53773,53777,53783,53791,53813,53819,53831,53849,53857,53861,53881,53887,53891,53897,53899,53917,53923,53927,53939,53951,53959,53987,53993,54121,54133,54139,54151,54163,54167,54181,54193,54217,54251,54269,54277,54287,54293,54311,54319,54323,54331,54347,54361,54367,54371,54377,54413,54419,54421,54437,54443,54449,54469,54493,54497,54499,54517,54521,54539,54541,54547,54559,54563,54577,54581,54583,54617,54623,54629,54631,54647,54667,54673,54679,54713,54721,54727,54751,54767,54773,54779,54787,54799,54829,54833,54851,54869,54877,54881,54917,54919,54941,54949,54959,54973,54979,54983,55117,55127,55147,55163,55171,55213,55217,55219,55229,55243,55249,55259,55291,55313,55331,55333,55337,55339,55343,55351,55373,55381,55399,55411,55439,55441,55457,55469,55487,55511,55529,55541,55547,55579,55589,55619,55621,55631,55633,55639,55661,55663,55667,55673,55681,55691,55697,55711,55717,55721,55733,55763,55787,55793,55799,55813,55817,55819,55823,55829,55837,55843,55849,55871,55889,55897,55921,55927,55931,55933,55949,55967,55987,55997,56113,56123,56131,56149,56167,56179,56197,56237,56239,56249,56263,56267,56269,56299,56311,56333,56359,56369,56377,56383,56393,56417,56431,56437,56443,56453,56467,56473,56477,56479,56489,56519,56527,56531,56533,56543,56569,56591,56597,56599,56611,56629,56633,56659,56663,56671,56681,56687,56713,56731,56737,56747,56767,56773,56779,56783,56813,56821,56827,56843,56857,56873,56891,56893,56897,56911,56921,56923,56929,56941,56951,56957,56963,56983,56989,56993,56999,57119,57139,57143,57149,57163,57173,57179,57191,57193,57221,57223,57241,57251,57259,57269,57271,57283,57287,57329,57331,57347,57349,57367,57373,57383,57389,57397,57413,57427,57457,57467,57487,57493,57527,57529,57557,57559,57571,57587,57593,57637,57641,57649,57653,57667,57679,57689,57697,57713,57719,57727,57731,57737,57751,57773,57781,57787,57791,57793,57829,57839,57847,57853,57859,57881,57899,57917,57923,57943,57947,57973,57977,57991,58111,58129,58147,58151,58153,58169,58171,58189,58193,58199,58211,58217,58229,58231,58237,58243,58271,58313,58321,58337,58363,58367,58369,58379,58391,58393,58411,58417,58427,58439,58441,58451,58453,58477,58481,58511,58537,58543,58549,58567,58573,58579,58613,58631,58657,58661,58679,58687,58693,58699,58711,58727,58733,58741,58757,58763,58771,58787,58789,58831,58889,58897,58913,58921,58937,58943,58963,58967,58979,58991,58997,59113,59119,59123,59141,59149,59159,59167,59183,59197,59219,59221,59233,59239,59243,59263,59273,59281,59333,59341,59351,59357,59359,59369,59377,59387,59393,59399,59417,59419,59441,59443,59447,59453,59467,59471,59473,59497,59513,59539,59557,59561,59567,59581,59611,59617,59621,59627,59629,59651,59659,59663,59669,59671,59693,59699,59723,59729,59743,59747,59753,59771,59779,59791,59797,59833,59863,59879,59887,59921,59929,59951,59957,59971,59981,59999,61121,61129,61141,61153,61169,61211,61223,61231,61253,61261,61283,61291,61297,61331,61333,61339,61343,61357,61363,61379,61381,61417,61441,61463,61469,61471,61483,61487,61493,61519,61543,61547,61553,61559,61561,61583,61613,61627,61631,61637,61643,61651,61657,61667,61673,61681,61687,61717,61723,61729,61757,61781,61813,61819,61837,61843,61861,61871,61879,61927,61933,61949,61961,61967,61979,61981,61987,61991,62119,62129,62131,62137,62141,62143,62171,62189,62191,62213,62219,62233,62273,62297,62299,62311,62323,62327,62347,62351,62383,62417,62423,62459,62467,62473,62477,62483,62497,62533,62539,62549,62563,62581,62591,62597,62617,62627,62633,62639,62653,62659,62683,62687,62723,62731,62743,62753,62761,62773,62791,62819,62827,62851,62861,62869,62873,62897,62921,62927,62929,62939,62969,62971,62981,62983,62987,62989,63113,63127,63131,63149,63179,63197,63199,63211,63241,63247,63277,63281,63299,63311,63313,63317,63331,63337,63347,63353,63361,63367,63377,63389,63391,63397,63419,63421,63439,63443,63463,63467,63473,63487,63493,63499,63521,63527,63533,63541,63559,63577,63587,63589,63599,63611,63617,63629,63647,63649,63659,63667,63671,63689,63691,63697,63719,63727,63737,63743,63761,63773,63781,63793,63799,63823,63839,63841,63853,63857,63863,63913,63929,63949,63977,63997,64123,64151,64153,64157,64171,64187,64189,64217,64223,64231,64237,64271,64279,64283,64319,64327,64333,64373,64381,64399,64433,64439,64451,64453,64483,64489,64499,64513,64553,64567,64577,64579,64591,64613,64621,64627,64633,64661,64663,64667,64679,64693,64717,64747,64763,64781,64783,64793,64811,64817,64849,64853,64871,64877,64879,64891,64919,64921,64927,64937,64951,64969,64997,65119,65123,65129,65141,65147,65167,65173,65179,65183,65213,65239,65257,65267,65269,65287,65293,65323,65327,65353,65357,65371,65381,65393,65413,65419,65423,65437,65447,65449,65479,65497,65519,65521,65537,65539,65543,65551,65557,65563,65579,65581,65587,65599,65617,65629,65633,65647,65651,65657,65677,65687,65699,65713,65717,65719,65729,65731,65761,65777,65789,65827,65831,65837,65839,65843,65851,65867,65881,65899,65921,65927,65929,65951,65957,65963,65981,65983,65993,66137,66161,66169,66173,66179,66191,66221,66239,66271,66293,66337,66343,66347,66359,66361,66373,66377,66383,66413,66431,66449,66457,66463,66467,66491,66499,66523,66529,66533,66541,66553,66569,66571,66587,66593,66617,66629,66643,66653,66683,66697,66713,66721,66733,66739,66749,66751,66763,66791,66797,66821,66841,66851,66853,66863,66877,66883,66889,66919,66923,66931,66943,66947,66949,66959,66973,66977,67121,67129,67139,67141,67153,67157,67169,67181,67187,67189,67211,67213,67217,67219,67231,67247,67261,67271,67273,67289,67339,67343,67349,67369,67391,67399,67411,67421,67427,67429,67433,67447,67453,67477,67481,67489,67493,67499,67523,67531,67537,67547,67559,67567,67577,67579,67589,67619,67631,67651,67679,67699,67723,67733,67741,67751,67757,67759,67763,67777,67783,67789,67819,67829,67843,67853,67867,67883,67891,67927,67931,67933,67939,67943,67957,67961,67967,67979,67987,67993,68111,68113,68141,68147,68161,68171,68213,68219,68227,68239,68261,68279,68281,68311,68329,68351,68371,68389,68399,68437,68443,68447,68449,68473,68477,68483,68489,68491,68521,68531,68539,68543,68567,68581,68597,68611,68633,68639,68659,68669,68683,68687,68699,68711,68713,68729,68737,68743,68749,68767,68771,68777,68791,68813,68819,68821,68863,68879,68881,68891,68897,68899,68917,68927,68947,68963,68993,69119,69127,69143,69149,69151,69163,69191,69193,69197,69221,69233,69239,69247,69257,69259,69263,69313,69317,69337,69341,69371,69379,69383,69389,69427,69431,69439,69457,69463,69467,69473,69481,69491,69493,69497,69499,69539,69557,69593,69623,69653,69661,69677,69691,69697,69737,69739,69761,69763,69767,69779,69821,69827,69829,69833,69847,69857,69859,69877,69899,69911,69929,69931,69941,69959,69991,69997,71119,71129,71143,71147,71167,71171,71191,71233,71237,71249,71257,71261,71263,71287,71293,71317,71327,71329,71333,71339,71341,71347,71353,71359,71363,71387,71389,71399,71411,71413,71419,71429,71437,71443,71453,71471,71473,71479,71483,71527,71537,71549,71551,71563,71569,71593,71597,71633,71647,71663,71671,71693,71699,71711,71713,71719,71741,71761,71777,71789,71821,71837,71843,71849,71861,71867,71879,71881,71887,71899,71917,71933,71941,71947,71963,71971,71983,71987,71993,71999,72139,72161,72167,72169,72173,72211,72221,72223,72227,72229,72251,72253,72269,72271,72277,72287,72313,72337,72341,72353,72367,72379,72383,72421,72431,72461,72467,72469,72481,72493,72497,72533,72547,72551,72559,72577,72613,72617,72623,72643,72647,72649,72661,72671,72673,72679,72689,72719,72727,72733,72739,72763,72767,72797,72817,72823,72859,72869,72871,72883,72889,72893,72911,72923,72931,72937,72949,72953,72959,72973,72977,72997,73127,73133,73141,73181,73189,73237,73243,73259,73277,73291,73327,73331,73351,73361,73363,73369,73379,73387,73417,73421,73433,73453,73459,73471,73477,73483,73517,73523,73529,73547,73553,73561,73571,73583,73589,73597,73613,73637,73643,73651,73673,73679,73681,73693,73699,73721,73727,73751,73757,73771,73783,73819,73823,73847,73849,73859,73867,73877,73883,73897,73939,73943,73951,73961,73973,73999,74131,74143,74149,74159,74161,74167,74177,74189,74197,74219,74231,74257,74279,74287,74293,74297,74311,74317,74323,74353,74357,74363,74377,74381,74383,74411,74413,74419,74441,74449,74453,74471,74489,74521,74527,74531,74551,74561,74567,74573,74587,74597,74611,74623,74653,74687,74699,74713,74717,74719,74729,74731,74747,74759,74761,74771,74779,74797,74821,74827,74831,74843,74857,74861,74869,74873,74887,74891,74897,74923,74929,74933,74941,74959,75133,75149,75167,75169,75181,75193,75217,75223,75227,75239,75253,75269,75277,75289,75323,75329,75337,75347,75353,75367,75377,75389,75391,75431,75437,75479,75511,75521,75527,75533,75539,75541,75553,75557,75571,75577,75583,75617,75619,75629,75641,75653,75659,75679,75683,75689,75721,75731,75743,75767,75773,75781,75787,75793,75797,75821,75833,75853,75869,75883,75913,75931,75937,75941,75967,75979,75983,75989,75991,75997,76123,76129,76147,76157,76159,76163,76213,76231,76243,76249,76253,76259,76261,76283,76289,76333,76343,76367,76369,76379,76387,76421,76423,76441,76463,76471,76481,76487,76493,76519,76537,76541,76543,76561,76579,76597,76631,76649,76651,76667,76673,76679,76697,76717,76733,76753,76757,76771,76777,76781,76819,76829,76831,76837,76847,76871,76873,76883,76913,76919,76943,76949,76961,76963,76991,77137,77141,77153,77167,77171,77191,77213,77237,77239,77243,77249,77261,77263,77267,77269,77279,77291,77317,77323,77339,77347,77351,77359,77369,77377,77383,77417,77419,77431,77447,77471,77477,77479,77489,77491,77513,77521,77527,77543,77549,77551,77557,77563,77569,77573,77587,77591,77611,77617,77621,77641,77647,77659,77681,77687,77689,77699,77711,77713,77719,77723,77731,77743,77747,77761,77773,77783,77797,77813,77839,77849,77863,77867,77893,77899,77929,77933,77951,77969,77977,77983,77999,78121,78137,78139,78157,78163,78167,78173,78179,78191,78193,78229,78233,78241,78259,78277,78283,78311,78317,78341,78347,78367,78427,78437,78439,78467,78479,78487,78497,78511,78517,78539,78541,78553,78569,78571,78577,78583,78593,78623,78643,78649,78653,78691,78697,78713,78721,78737,78779,78781,78787,78791,78797,78823,78839,78853,78857,78877,78887,78889,78893,78919,78929,78941,78977,78979,78989,79111,79133,79139,79147,79151,79153,79159,79181,79187,79193,79229,79231,79241,79259,79273,79279,79283,79319,79333,79337,79349,79357,79367,79379,79393,79397,79399,79411,79423,79427,79433,79451,79481,79493,79531,79537,79549,79559,79561,79579,79589,79613,79621,79627,79631,79633,79657,79669,79687,79691,79693,79697,79699,79757,79769,79777,79811,79813,79817,79823,79829,79841,79843,79847,79861,79867,79873,79889,79939,79943,79967,79973,79979,79987,79997,79999,81119,81131,81157,81163,81173,81181,81197,81199,81223,81233,81239,81281,81283,81293,81299,81331,81343,81349,81353,81359,81371,81373,81421,81439,81457,81463,81517,81527,81533,81547,81551,81553,81559,81563,81569,81611,81619,81629,81637,81647,81649,81667,81671,81677,81689,81727,81737,81749,81761,81769,81773,81799,81817,81839,81847,81853,81869,81883,81899,81919,81929,81931,81937,81943,81953,81967,81971,81973,82129,82139,82141,82153,82163,82171,82183,82189,82193,82217,82219,82223,82231,82237,82241,82261,82267,82279,82339,82349,82351,82361,82373,82387,82393,82421,82457,82463,82469,82471,82483,82487,82493,82499,82529,82531,82549,82559,82561,82567,82571,82591,82613,82619,82633,82651,82657,82699,82721,82723,82727,82729,82757,82759,82763,82781,82787,82793,82799,82811,82813,82837,82847,82883,82889,82891,82913,82939,82963,82981,82997,83117,83137,83177,83219,83221,83227,83231,83233,83243,83257,83267,83269,83273,83299,83311,83339,83341,83357,83383,83389,83399,83417,83423,83431,83437,83443,83449,83459,83471,83477,83497,83537,83557,83561,83563,83579,83591,83597,83617,83621,83639,83641,83653,83663,83689,83717,83719,83737,83761,83773,83777,83791,83813,83833,83843,83857,83869,83873,83891,83911,83921,83933,83939,83969,83983,83987,84121,84127,84131,84137,84143,84163,84179,84181,84191,84199,84211,84221,84223,84229,84239,84247,84263,84299,84313,84317,84319,84347,84349,84377,84389,84391,84421,84431,84437,84443,84449,84457,84463,84467,84481,84499,84521,84523,84533,84551,84559,84589,84629,84631,84649,84653,84659,84673,84691,84697,84713,84719,84731,84737,84751,84761,84787,84793,84811,84827,84857,84859,84869,84871,84913,84919,84947,84961,84967,84977,84979,84991,85121,85133,85147,85159,85193,85199,85213,85223,85229,85237,85243,85247,85259,85297,85313,85331,85333,85361,85363,85369,85381,85411,85427,85429,85439,85447,85451,85453,85469,85487,85513,85517,85523,85531,85549,85571,85577,85597,85619,85621,85627,85639,85643,85661,85667,85669,85691,85711,85717,85733,85751,85781,85793,85817,85819,85829,85831,85837,85843,85847,85853,85889,85931,85933,85991,85999,86111,86113,86117,86131,86137,86143,86161,86171,86179,86183,86197,86239,86243,86249,86257,86263,86269,86287,86291,86293,86297,86311,86323,86341,86351,86353,86357,86369,86371,86381,86389,86399,86413,86423,86441,86453,86461,86467,86477,86491,86531,86533,86539,86561,86573,86579,86587,86599,86627,86629,86677,86689,86693,86711,86719,86729,86743,86753,86767,86771,86783,86813,86837,86843,86851,86857,86861,86869,86923,86927,86929,86939,86951,86959,86969,86981,86993,87119,87121,87133,87149,87151,87179,87181,87187,87211,87221,87223,87251,87253,87257,87277,87281,87293,87299,87313,87317,87323,87337,87359,87383,87421,87427,87433,87443,87473,87481,87491,87511,87517,87523,87539,87541,87547,87553,87557,87559,87583,87587,87589,87613,87623,87629,87631,87641,87643,87649,87671,87679,87683,87691,87697,87719,87721,87739,87743,87751,87767,87793,87797,87811,87833,87853,87869,87877,87881,87887,87911,87917,87931,87943,87959,87961,87973,87977,87991,88117,88129,88169,88177,88211,88223,88237,88241,88259,88261,88289,88321,88327,88337,88339,88379,88397,88411,88423,88427,88463,88469,88471,88493,88499,88513,88523,88547,88589,88591,88643,88651,88657,88661,88663,88667,88681,88721,88729,88741,88747,88771,88789,88793,88799,88811,88813,88817,88819,88843,88853,88861,88867,88873,88883,88897,88919,88937,88951,88969,88993,88997,89113,89119,89123,89137,89153,89189,89213,89227,89231,89237,89261,89269,89273,89293,89317,89329,89363,89371,89381,89387,89393,89399,89413,89417,89431,89443,89449,89459,89477,89491,89513,89519,89521,89527,89533,89561,89563,89567,89591,89597,89599,89611,89627,89633,89653,89657,89659,89669,89671,89681,89689,89753,89759,89767,89779,89783,89797,89819,89821,89833,89839,89849,89867,89891,89897,89899,89917,89923,89939,89959,89963,89977,89983,89989,91121,91127,91129,91139,91141,91151,91153,91159,91163,91183,91193,91199,91229,91237,91243,91249,91253,91283,91291,91297,91331,91367,91369,91373,91381,91387,91393,91397,91411,91423,91433,91453,91457,91459,91463,91493,91499,91513,91529,91541,91571,91573,91577,91583,91591,91621,91631,91639,91673,91691,91711,91733,91753,91757,91771,91781,91811,91813,91823,91837,91841,91867,91873,91921,91939,91943,91951,91957,91961,91967,91969,91997,92111,92119,92143,92153,92173,92177,92179,92189,92219,92221,92227,92233,92237,92243,92251,92269,92297,92311,92317,92333,92347,92353,92357,92363,92369,92377,92381,92383,92387,92399,92413,92419,92431,92459,92461,92467,92479,92489,92551,92557,92567,92569,92581,92593,92623,92627,92639,92641,92647,92657,92669,92671,92681,92683,92693,92699,92717,92723,92737,92753,92761,92767,92779,92789,92791,92821,92831,92849,92857,92861,92863,92867,92893,92899,92921,92927,92941,92951,92957,92959,92987,92993,93113,93131,93133,93139,93151,93169,93179,93187,93199,93229,93239,93241,93251,93253,93257,93263,93281,93283,93287,93319,93323,93329,93337,93371,93377,93383,93419,93427,93463,93479,93481,93487,93491,93493,93497,93523,93529,93553,93557,93559,93563,93581,93629,93637,93683,93719,93739,93761,93763,93787,93811,93827,93851,93871,93887,93889,93893,93911,93913,93923,93937,93941,93949,93967,93971,93979,93983,93997,94111,94117,94121,94151,94153,94169,94219,94229,94253,94261,94273,94291,94321,94327,94331,94343,94349,94351,94379,94397,94399,94421,94427,94433,94439,94441,94447,94463,94477,94483,94513,94529,94531,94541,94543,94547,94559,94561,94573,94583,94597,94613,94621,94649,94651,94687,94693,94723,94727,94747,94771,94777,94781,94789,94793,94811,94819,94823,94837,94841,94847,94849,94873,94889,94933,94949,94951,94961,94993,94999,95111,95131,95143,95153,95177,95189,95191,95213,95219,95231,95233,95239,95257,95261,95267,95273,95279,95287,95311,95317,95327,95339,95369,95383,95393,95413,95419,95429,95441,95443,95461,95467,95471,95479,95483,95527,95531,95539,95549,95561,95569,95581,95597,95617,95621,95629,95633,95651,95713,95717,95723,95731,95737,95747,95773,95783,95789,95791,95813,95819,95857,95869,95873,95881,95891,95911,95917,95923,95929,95947,95957,95959,95971,95987,95989,96137,96149,96157,96167,96179,96181,96199,96211,96221,96223,96233,96259,96263,96269,96281,96289,96293,96323,96329,96331,96337,96353,96377,96419,96431,96443,96451,96457,96461,96469,96479,96487,96493,96497,96517,96527,96553,96557,96581,96587,96589,96643,96661,96667,96671,96697,96731,96737,96739,96749,96757,96763,96769,96779,96787,96797,96799,96821,96823,96827,96847,96851,96857,96893,96911,96931,96953,96959,96973,96979,96989,96997,97117,97127,97151,97157,97159,97169,97171,97177,97187,97213,97231,97241,97259,97283,97327,97367,97369,97373,97379,97381,97387,97397,97423,97429,97441,97453,97459,97463,97499,97511,97523,97547,97549,97553,97561,97571,97577,97579,97583,97613,97649,97651,97673,97687,97711,97729,97771,97777,97787,97789,97813,97829,97841,97843,97847,97849,97859,97861,97871,97879,97883,97919,97927,97931,97943,97961,97967,97973,97987,98123,98129,98143,98179,98213,98221,98227,98251,98257,98269,98297,98299,98317,98321,98323,98327,98347,98369,98377,98387,98389,98411,98419,98429,98443,98453,98459,98467,98473,98479,98491,98519,98533,98543,98561,98563,98573,98597,98621,98627,98639,98641,98663,98669,98689,98711,98713,98717,98729,98731,98737,98773,98779,98837,98849,98867,98869,98873,98887,98893,98897,98899,98911,98927,98929,98939,98947,98953,98963,98981,98993,98999,99119,99131,99133,99137,99139,99149,99173,99181,99191,99223,99233,99241,99251,99257,99259,99277,99289,99317,99347,99349,99367,99371,99377,99391,99397,99431,99439,99469,99487,99497,99523,99527,99529,99551,99559,99563,99571,99577,99581,99611,99623,99643,99661,99667,99679,99689,99713,99719,99721,99733,99761,99767,99787,99793,99817,99823,99829,99833,99839,99859,99871,99877,99881,99923,99929,99961,99971,99989,99991$